# Generate private keys and x509 certificates using the Golang crypto package's code，unable to connect to my mqtts server normally

Tags: go, mqtt, x509certificate

I need to generate a private key and certificate to connect to my MQTT server.

I generated a private key and a certificate using Go's `crypto` package, but I am unable to connect to my MQTT server properly. But the certificate I created through OpenSSL based on the private key I generated using Go code can connect to my MQTT server normally.

**go version:**
go version go1.20.1 darwin/arm64

I haven't tried the latest version of Go yet

I used this code to create a private key and certificate:

```
func GenerateCertificate(certificatePath string, keyPath string) error {
    key, _ := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)

    serialNumber, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, (&big.Int{}).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(159), nil))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    now := time.Now()
    template := x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: serialNumber,
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            CommonName:   "localhost",
            Country:      []string{"AU"},
            Organization: []string{"Internet Widgits Pty Ltd"},
            Province:     []string{"Some-State"},
        },
        Issuer: pkix.Name{
            CommonName:   "localhost",
            Country:      []string{"AU"},
            Organization: []string{"Internet Widgits Pty Ltd"},
            Province:     []string{"Some-State"},
        },
        NotBefore:          now,
        NotAfter:           now.AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        PublicKeyAlgorithm: x509.ECDSA,
        SignatureAlgorithm: x509.ECDSAWithSHA256,
    }

    derBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, &key.PublicKey, key)
    var certificateOut, keyOut io.Writer

    if _, e := os.Stat(keyPath); os.IsNotExist(e) {
        if _, err = os.Create(keyPath); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    keyOut, err = os.OpenFile(keyPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if _, e := os.Stat(certificatePath); os.IsNotExist(e) {
        if _, err = os.Create(certificatePath); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    certificateOut, err = os.OpenFile(certificatePath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    secp256r1, err := asn1.Marshal(asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    paramBlock := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "EC PARAMETERS", Bytes: secp256r1})
    if _, err := keyOut.Write(paramBlock); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    b, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(key)
    privBlock := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "EC PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: b})
    
    if _, err := keyOut.Write(privBlock);err != nil {
        return err
    }

    certBlock := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: derBytes})

    certificateOut.Write(certBlock)
    return nil
}
```

Next, I will use the created private key and certificate to connect to my MQTT server:

```
func NewTLSConfig(certFile string, privateKey string) (*tls.Config, error) {

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &tls.Config{
        ClientAuth:         tls.NoClientCert,
        ClientCAs:          nil,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
        MaxVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }, nil
}

if tlsConfig, err := util.NewTLSConfig("./config/certs/cert.pem", "./config/certs/key.pem"); err == nil {
    opts.SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)
} else {
    return err
}

t.Client = mqtt.NewClient(opts)
if token := t.Client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
    logrus.Error("Connect to Thingsboard failed:", token.Error())
    return token.Error()
}
```

**And then my MQTT server couldn't receive any certificates**
[image: Screenshot of MQTT server debugging]

But I used the openssl command to create a certificate based on the private key I created using Golang code, and then connected to my MQTT server in the same way, which is normal. The command is as follows:

```
openssl req -new -key key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out cert.pem
```

[image: Screenshot of openssl command]

Using that cert works:
[image: Screenshot of mqtts server debugging]

I use the following command to view two certificates so that I can see their differences. But I still don't know where the problem lies:

**openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout**

**Cert.pem generated by Golang code:**

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        46:27:bf:6e:a5:1d:c8:f1:2c:bd:9d:7c:9f:93:37:c2:bf:06:04:82
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = localhost
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep 23 08:38:55 2023 GMT
        Not After : Sep 23 08:38:55 2024 GMT
    Subject: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = localhost
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                04:95:97:c6:ad:c1:30:ac:34:38:ef:e7:3a:a8:77:
                77:1d:d0:16:4d:fc:7f:58:b0:1e:d7:95:1b:eb:66:
                a2:d1:35:82:b4:95:fc:9b:61:dd:c0:e0:d5:d2:44:
                23:37:6e:81:38:1f:7d:8c:70:46:b8:15:7b:fa:ba:
                fe:8e:4b:ba:ac
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            54:C8:FB:98:E9:64:49:74:13:1D:ED:25:95:50:34:D1:16:BB:9C:8E
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Signature Value:
    30:45:02:20:54:fd:b2:7a:07:ff:b2:57:16:d4:1a:c8:5d:b1:
    2e:36:11:4c:39:1f:8d:1f:b3:20:a7:d4:73:f4:fd:3e:33:8c:
    02:21:00:fa:5c:c6:aa:28:5f:a2:bf:fe:34:27:ff:91:ef:b8:
    f2:9d:01:2f:03:51:35:af:39:e4:fe:db:b6:f7:f6:56:c1
```

**Cert.pem generated by openssl:**

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        5e:ff:6d:43:81:ca:68:87:f7:15:e8:0d:7c:4c:7e:19:68:a8:2a:8c
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = localhost
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep 23 08:40:26 2023 GMT
        Not After : Sep 22 08:40:26 2024 GMT
    Subject: C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = localhost
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub:
                04:95:97:c6:ad:c1:30:ac:34:38:ef:e7:3a:a8:77:
                77:1d:d0:16:4d:fc:7f:58:b0:1e:d7:95:1b:eb:66:
                a2:d1:35:82:b4:95:fc:9b:61:dd:c0:e0:d5:d2:44:
                23:37:6e:81:38:1f:7d:8c:70:46:b8:15:7b:fa:ba:
                fe:8e:4b:ba:ac
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            54:C8:FB:98:E9:64:49:74:13:1D:ED:25:95:50:34:D1:16:BB:9C:8E
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            54:C8:FB:98:E9:64:49:74:13:1D:ED:25:95:50:34:D1:16:BB:9C:8E
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Signature Value:
    30:45:02:20:79:87:61:84:90:1f:a5:28:ae:98:8d:6f:7c:f4:
    cf:ae:fd:64:70:0d:78:b3:0b:cc:bf:cb:22:7c:46:4c:9c:76:
    02:21:00:c0:23:6a:0d:27:ea:8a:11:1b:32:53:62:ae:df:0d:
    41:26:f6:5c:f5:33:04:14:15:2b:7f:64:d6:dd:ab:dc:7d
```

May I ask what I should do to ensure that the `cert.pem` created by my code can be used to connect with my secure MQTT server?

Comment: Can you give me a complete and usable code？Or teach me how to use Golang code to implement the following commands.Thank you very much!!

Comment: openssl ecparam -out key.pem -name secp256r1 -genkey

Comment: openssl req -new -key key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out cert.pem

Comment: From a glance I think you will need to set `x509.Certificate.NotAfter` otherwise your cert will not be valid. Run `openssl.exe x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout` over both certs and add the output to the question (this will let us see the differences). Generally when using a cert for client auth you would use a CA (which may be self generated) to sign so the broker can validate the cert.

Comment: @Brits Thank you. Your answer did not solve my problem

Comment: I have used your code to generate a certificate and successfully used that to auth with Mosquitto (easiest broker for me to run); this indicates that the certificate is OK - for completeness here is the [code I used](https://go.dev/play/p/Mmj8vzVuflG). Note that the certificate generated does not have the "X509v3 extensions" yours does (not sure why; I am using go 1.21.1). So this seems to be an incompatibility with your specific broker (or maybe code you have not shown us), so I'd suggest refocusing your question (provide a generated cert and ask things board users why its not accepted).